# How to add a new HTML ID each time a user posts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on creating a randomized color ID each time a new post is made.

The problem is I don't know how to make a new HTML `<span>` with a new #ID in it every time, in the view/HTML. I can't attach the unique color information to the unique Id text without generating a new...

```
<span =[new id here]>
```

...in the HTML every time. This is kind of confusing me to be honest. I am not sure where my code is lacking most. The logic is kind of making my head spin. I've already got it working to where a new post attaches a new ID every time, however I can't figure out how to ensure that the new color is always attached to the related ID every time the page loads, and in addition I would like to make it so that if the ID is "replied" to it will again copy the CSS into that area.

If I could focus down to one question I'd like answered though, it's just how to generate the new HTML span.

So basically what I'm hoping to do is have it like this (rough explanation):

javascript code:

```
//create the ID and into database

var ID = [the ID as generated from the database];

//create the colors and into database

IDcolor = (color generator)

//get that unique ID in the span and put the color into it

$('#[ID]').css('color', IDcolor);
```

in the view (ejs):

```
<span id= [put the above generated ID here]><%= text goes here %></span>
```

Edit: I'm very new to this - however I have got the random ID system working and posting into my view and storing the random ID into the database. I also already have the random color generator working (though not attaching yet). The problem is that I can't use that info unless I can generate a new Span/ID in the view and this is where I am becoming confused and lost. Also my understanding of jQuery is kind of low - mostly just unsure where to look.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking it.  You could do something as simple as:

```
$('body').append('<span id='+ID+'>some description here</span>').css('color', IDcolor);
```

```js
function init() {
 var ID = "foo";
 var IDcolor = "red";
 $('body').append('<span id='+ID+'>some description here</span>').css('color', IDcolor);
}

$(init);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the +ID+ inserts a variable by the name ID into the string?

Comment: Yup.  I'll modify the answer slightly with more detail

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful.